# Why are my div elements overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I've looked at a couple of the different posts regarding this issue that i'm having and haven't found any solutions to my problem. The problem that i'm having is that the elements in my "portfolio" section are overlapping in the "about me" section. I've tried applying the overflow: hidden and overflow: auto properties to my code and nothing has seemed to work! Here is my code on JSFiddle if any of you have any suggestions I would be happy to hear them! Thanks!

```css
/* Mobile Navigation */

#mobile-nav {
  display: none;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #262626;
}

#mobile-nav .mobile-nav-tgl-btn {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 12.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mobile-nav .mobile-nav-tgl-btn .bar {
  height: 7.5px;
  width: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 6.25px;
  margin-bottom: 6.25px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

#mobile-nav .nav-links {
  text-align: center;
}

#mobile-nav .nav-links ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 4;
}

#mobile-nav .nav-links ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#mobile-nav .nav-links ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}


/* Nomral Navigation */

#norm-navbar {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #262626;
}

#norm-navbar .norm-nav-links {
  padding-top: 16.5px;
  float: left;
}

#norm-navbar .norm-social-links {
  padding-top: 16.5px;
  float: right;
}

#norm-navbar a {
  font-size: 1.85em;
  /* 29.6px font-size */
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}


/* Site header */

#header-section {
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#header-section .header-elements {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}

#header-section .header-elements img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#header-section .header-elements h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

#header-section .page-down-btn {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#header-section .page-down-btn p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#header-section .page-down-btn i {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#header-section .page-down-btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/* About me section */

#about-me {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
}

#about-me .left-panel {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  height: 450px;
}

#about-me .left-panel h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#about-me .left-panel .about-me-para {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#about-me .left-panel .about-me-para p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#about-me .right-panel {
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  background-image: url("http://cdn.zmescience.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/over_the_edge.jpg");
  height: 497px;
}


/* Portfolio/work section */

#work-section {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-nav">
  <button class="mobile-nav-tgl-btn">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </button>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="norm-navbar">
  <div class="norm-nav-links">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="norm-social-links">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-codepen" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="header-section">
  <div class="header-elements">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/2000px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    <h1>Hi, I'm a website developer that loves to make <strong>stunning</strong> and <strong>functional</strong> websites.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page-down-btn">
    <p>Click to learn more</p>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="about-me">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <div class="left-panel-cont">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <div class="sm-sep"></div>
      <div class="about-me-para">
        <p class="para-1">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

        <br>

        <p class="para-2">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right-panel">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="work-section">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pv5s6s0w/

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Please add float:left to #work-section class

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/pv5s6s0w/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed `height: 450px;` for #about-me .left-panel. The text inside the div is overflowing it. The reason why it overlaps is you have given `position: absolute;` for about me section. Also added `display: inline-block;` for id work-section.

```css
/* Mobile Navigation */

#mobile-nav {
  display: none;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #262626;
}

#mobile-nav .mobile-nav-tgl-btn {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 12.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mobile-nav .mobile-nav-tgl-btn .bar {
  height: 7.5px;
  width: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 6.25px;
  margin-bottom: 6.25px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

#mobile-nav .nav-links {
  text-align: center;
}

#mobile-nav .nav-links ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 4;
}

#mobile-nav .nav-links ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#mobile-nav .nav-links ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}


/* Nomral Navigation */

#norm-navbar {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #262626;
}

#norm-navbar .norm-nav-links {
  padding-top: 16.5px;
  float: left;
}

#norm-navbar .norm-social-links {
  padding-top: 16.5px;
  float: right;
}

#norm-navbar a {
  font-size: 1.85em;
  /* 29.6px font-size */
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}


/* Site header */

#header-section {
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#header-section .header-elements {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}

#header-section .header-elements img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#header-section .header-elements h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

#header-section .page-down-btn {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#header-section .page-down-btn p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#header-section .page-down-btn i {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#header-section .page-down-btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/* About me section */

#about-me {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#about-me .left-panel {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

#about-me .left-panel h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#about-me .left-panel .about-me-para {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#about-me .left-panel .about-me-para p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#about-me .right-panel {
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  background-image: url("http://cdn.zmescience.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/over_the_edge.jpg");
  height: 497px;
}


/* Portfolio/work section */

#work-section {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-nav">
  <button class="mobile-nav-tgl-btn">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </button>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="norm-navbar">
  <div class="norm-nav-links">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="norm-social-links">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-codepen" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="header-section">
  <div class="header-elements">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/2000px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png" alt="Logo">
    <h1>Hi, I'm a website developer that loves to make <strong>stunning</strong> and <strong>functional</strong> websites.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page-down-btn">
    <p>Click to learn more</p>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="about-me">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <div class="left-panel-cont">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <div class="sm-sep"></div>
      <div class="about-me-para">
        <p class="para-1">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

        <br>

        <p class="para-2">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right-panel">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="work-section">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @WebAlchemist  Try this.

Comment: Thank you! So the reason that the text was overflowing was because of the position abosolute?

Comment: The main problem was that you gave a fixed height for the div.